# mysql IF statement problem

Tags: mysql

I  have this  UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION merge(user_id INT) RETURNS TEXT
BEGIN
DECLARE dsc TEXT;
     IF user_id = 1
      --some SQL statements
      END IF;
    RETURN dsc;
END//
```

For some reason even if the value of user_id is != 1 --some SQL statements are executed.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION merge(_USER_ID INT) 
RETURNS TEXT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
DECLARE _DSC TEXT;
     IF _USER_ID = 1 THEN
      --some SQL statements
     END IF;
    RETURN (_DSC);
END//
```

Comment: Now working for me. --some sql statements is still executed even user_id is not 1